# Proper way on putting images as sources in assets shopify

Tags: css, shopify

I've been stuck in showing custom social on top of shopify theme. I tried the `{{ 'icon.png' | asset_url }}` but it won't display. Instead when I check the element in the browser it automatically generates a style which is `display: none !important;`. I don't know where or what I'm missing.

Here's my code below:

```
<div id="smash-social" class="grid__item medium-up--two-fifths text-right">
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/link" target="_blank">
            {{ 'facebook-logo-button.png' | asset_url }}
          </a>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/link" target="_blank">
            {{ 'twitter-logo-button.png' | asset_url }}
          </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, @claudios... do you think you could disclose the theme that you're using? @jrbedard's answer below is correct. It's almost certainly some javascript that is adding these inline styles to your `<img>` tag. Try taking them out of the `#smash-social` element and see if they're still hidden, for starters.

Comment: @CameronHurd, Yeah! something's not right really. I'll try to remove that.

Comment: @CameronHurd, tried but no joy :(

Comment: @CameronHurd, I get it now! It's because of my adBlock Plus chrome plugin that blocks my images to show up. Phew!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the [`img_tag`](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/html-filters#img_tag) filter to generate an `img` HTML element complete with an alt attribute:

```
{{ 'facebook-logo-button.png' | asset_url | img_tag: 'facebook' }}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that also but it wont show. When I inspect the element it gives me this `<img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1363/4483/t/10/assets/facebook-logo-button.png?4918099405809607113" alt="facebook" style="display: none !important;">`

Comment: Hey man I get it now. It's just because of my adBlock plus chrome plugin that blocks my images.